# Filter all but English characters from a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, `df`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1,2,3,4,5],
           "eng_mand" :["後山 73reviews Community Center 竹杉園休閒農場",
                        "Taipei City 42台北市Taiwan",
                        "綠山谷海芋園餐廳reviews",
                        "名陽匍65休閒農莊minyangpu大賞園",
                        "Menghuanhu"]})
```

which looks like:

```
   ID                               eng_mand
0   1  後山 73reviews Community Center 竹杉園休閒農場
1   2                Taipei City 42台北市Taiwan
2   3                        綠山谷海芋園餐廳reviews
3   4                  名陽匍65休閒農莊minyangpu大賞園
4   5                             Menghuanhu
```

I want to take all but the english characters from the column `eng_mand` and put that in another column `new_col` .

The output should look like:

```
   ID                               eng_mand                   new_col
0   1  後山 73reviews Community Center 竹杉園休閒農場           後山 73 竹杉園休閒農場
1   2                Taipei City 42台北市Taiwan                42台北市
2   3                        綠山谷海芋園餐廳reviews            綠山谷海芋園餐廳
3   4                  名陽匍65休閒農莊minyangpu大賞園          名陽匍65休閒農莊大賞園
4   5                             Menghuanhu
```

How can I do that in pandas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['new'] = df['eng_mand'].str.replace('[a-zA-Z]', '')
print (df)
  ID                               eng_mand              new
0   1  後山 73reviews Community Center 竹杉園休閒農場  後山 73   竹杉園休閒農場
1   2                Taipei City 42台北市Taiwan            42台北市
2   3                        綠山谷海芋園餐廳reviews         綠山谷海芋園餐廳
3   4                  名陽匍65休閒農莊minyangpu大賞園     名陽匍65休閒農莊大賞園
4   5                             Menghuanhu
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), but including also all special characters such as accents, such as `"éòàç"` etc...:

```
regex = "[^\d\W⺀-⺙⺛-⻳⼀-⿕々〇〡-〩〸-〺〻㐀-䶵一-鿃豈-鶴侮-頻並-龎]"
df["new"] = df["eng_mand"].str.replace(regex, "")
```

With the result being:

```
0    後山 73   竹杉園休閒農場
1              42台北市
2           綠山谷海芋園餐廳
3       名陽匍65休閒農莊大賞園
4
```